# Radon-Nikodym derivative between $\eta$ and its empirical approximation obtained through importance resampling

Tags: probability, resampling, measure-theory, importance-sampling, sequential-monte-carlo

Suppose I have a probability measure $\eta$ on a measurable space $(\mathsf{X}, \mathcal{X})$ and I have an empirical approximation of it
$$
\eta^N(dx) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \delta_{X^{(i)}}(dx)
$$
for some particles $X^{(i)}$ that I have obtained through importance **resampling** with a proposal measure $\nu$.

> Is the Radon-Nikodym derivative between $\eta$ and $\eta^N$ evaluated at any $X^{(i)}$ constant?
> $$
> \frac{d\eta}{d\eta^N}(X^{(i)}) = \text{constant}
> $$

## Additional Information

We have first sampled $\tilde{X}^{(i)}\sim \nu$ for $i=1, \ldots, N$ and then computed weights
$$
w(\tilde{X}^{(i)}) = \frac{d\eta}{d\nu}(\tilde{X}^{(i)})
$$
to form the weighted particle approximation
$$
\tilde{\eta}^N(dx) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N w(\tilde{X}^{(i)})\delta_{\tilde{X}^{(i)}}(dx)
$$
then we sample
$$
X^{(i)} \sim \tilde{\eta}^N
$$
which form the particle approximation $\eta^N(dx)$ in the main body of the question.